# save EventQueue events and restore

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, eventqueue

Is it possible to save pending events from event queue and then restore them?

There is following workflow: user click on JTable row and there is a check if row is changed, depending on that check modal confirmation window is opened. When user double clicks row detail view is opened. So when modal window is opened it swallows all mouse events and thus double click does not reach JTable.

I wanted somehow save all pending events from event queue before opening modal window and restore them after modal window is closed.

Following I tried

```
EventQueue eventQueue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
Stack<AWTEvent> events = new Stack<AWTEvent>();
PaintEvent pe = new PaintEvent(DetailPanel.this, PaintEvent.PAINT, new Rectangle(10, 10));
eventQueue.postEvent(pe);
while (eventQueue.peekEvent() != null) {
    AWTEvent event = eventQueue.getNextEvent();
    events.push(event);
}
..... // modal window code
while(!events.isEmpty()) {
    eventQueue.postEvent(events.pop());
}
```

This does not help, double click does not reach JTable.

Also I tried pushing whole queue:

```
EventQueue stackQueue = new EventQueue();
EventQueue eventQueue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
stackQueue.push(eventQueue);
... //modal window code
eventQueue.push(stackQueue);
```

In this case programs seems to be deadlocked.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why not just check the mouse clicked count [MouseEvent#getClickCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount())

Comment: @MadProgrammer, mouse clicks and row change are processed in different handlers.

Comment: @misha nesterenko isn't better to use Java7, there is possible to create secondary loop :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I found issue. There should not be `Stack`, just ordinary FIFO collection.

So following schema correctly saved and restored events

```
EventQueue eventQueue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
List<AWTEvent> events = new ArrayList<AWTEvent>();
eventQueue.postEvent(new PaintEvent(DetailPanel.this, PaintEvent.PAINT, new Rectangle(10, 10));
while (eventQueue.peekEvent() != null) {
    events.add(eventQueue.getNextEvent());
}
..... // modal window code
For (AWTEvent event : events) {
    eventQueue.postEvent(event);
}
```